# Drools - check if exists/contains string in a List<String>

Tags: java, scala, drools

I need to create a rule to check if a part of string exists inside a List[String]. Is there a way that i could do it?

I'm trying using **contains** but it's not working.

```
rule "New Assistance"
    when
        $room:Room($tags : tags)
        //$room:Room(tags contains "protocol")
        $value:String() from $tags
        //Boolean(booleanValue == true) from $value == "protocol"
        Boolean(booleanValue == true) from $value.contains("protocol")
    then
        System.out.println("Error");
end
```

And here is my code

```
...
val room = new Room(null, List[User](), List[Message](message), 
            new Date, null, List[String]("protocol"))
kieSession.insert(room)
kieSession.fireAllRules()
....
```

Thanks!

// tests java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
        tags.add("protocol");
        Room room = new Room(tags);
        System.out.println(room.tags.contains("protocol") );        
    }   
}

class Room {        
    public List<String> tags;

    public Room(List<String> tags){
        this.tags = tags;
    }   
}
```

// tests scala

```
val room = new Room(null, List[User](), List[Message](message), 
            new Date, null, List[String]("protocol"))

var xx = room.tags.contains("protocol")
```

Both returns **true**.

Comment: Try : $value.toLowerCase().contains("protocol") to eliminate case differences.

Comment: @I.K. This is rather desperate.

Comment: @laune, I'm only trying to eliminate possible sources of error. Have you not read any Sherlock Holmes novels ;)

Comment: Possibly more than you: "Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth." :-))

Comment: @laune, Touche! More seriously, I am beginning to see quite a few posts now with people trying to use Scala with Drools. Not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: @I.K. I've launched an inquiry with the Drools Team to learn whether they ever have endorsed using Scala in combination with Drools.

Comment: @I.K. it's working with Java. The same code that i did in Scala, works in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rule "New Assistance"
when
    $room:Room($tags : tags contains "protocol")
then
    System.out.println("Error");
end
```

Comment: Not working. Any chance to be a incompatibility between Drools/Scala?

Comment: It does work, i.e., the rule is correct, tested using Drools 5.5.0. - Can you write a Java program that accesses a Room object created as shown and where `room.getTags().contains( "protocol" )` returns true?

Comment: I'm using Drools 6.1.0 and it's not working. I've wrote the code that you said on Java and Scala..both returns true. I paste the code on topic.

Comment: Well, it sure works in 6.1.0 as well. - I just wonder: has there been any announcement that Drools should work in combination with Scala? It's not quite as simple as the usual Java - Scala interaction.

Comment: I'll create a project on Java with Drools and check if it's any problem on Scala.

Comment: it's working with Java. The same code that i did in Scala, works in Java.

Comment: Which means that Drools and Scala cannot cooperate? - Whoever said it's possible?

Comment: If Scala runs on JVM, it should be possible, right? A lot of presentations about scala says that is possible to use all java libraries on scala.

Comment: It's not as simple as that. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323507/creating-new-scala-object-in-drools-right-hand-side or join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70248/discussion-on-question-by-groomedgorilla-creating-new-scala-object-in-drools-rig